# How to handle Maven dependencies that are not yet added to mvnrepository?

Tags: maven, jenkins

I'm building a plugin for Jenkins using Maven and i have [Yahoo UI Compressor](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.yahoo.platform.yui/yuicompressor) as a dependency.
The issue is that mvnrepository.com has only version 2.4.7 while they have released 2.4.8 quite some time ago. 
What can i do in this case to get 2.4.8 working (and use) as a dependency for my plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your local(downloaded) jar file as dependency. Please do following.

1:- Place downloaded file somewhere in your project.

2:- Add dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>yourjarname</groupId>
    <artifactId>yourjarname</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

3:- Run following command to add your local downloaded jar as dependency.

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=yourjarname -DartifactId=yourjarname -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=1.0 -Dfile=F:\WorkSpace\yourproject\lib\yourjar.jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

Comment: I have tried this but it still searches for the dependency on the remote mvn repo and not on my local one, saying that the 2.4.8 version is not found.     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.yahoo.platform.yui</groupId>
            <artifactId>yuicompressor</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>   Should i give it another name? or is there a way to make the maven look first on local repos and only after that on the remote ones?

Comment: You have to cross verify that your local jar is successfully installed. Run command mentioned in step 3 first. You command will look like `mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.yahoo.platform.yui -DartifactId=yuicompressor -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=2.4.7 -Dfile=F:\WorkSpace\yourproject\lib\yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar -DgeneratePom=true`. Then go to your local maven repository folder and verify that it is successfully installed. Your default maven repository folder will be at C:\Users\punit\.m2\repository\com\yahoo\platform\yui. It should resolve dependency if installation is successful.

Answer (score 2):

It might be the best to use [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22com.yahoo.platform.yui%22%20AND%20a%3a%22yuicompressor%22) instead something different. If on the other hand the people of the uicompressor didn't released the new artifact on Maven central it's not really good idea. I don't see a 2.4.8 in Maven central.